# Is there an Android TextVew Widget XML Attribute to display from the bottom of a string

Tags: android, xml, textview, widget

I have a textview widget where in my program I always have to scroll down to the bottom of the text to see the last elements of the text string.

The text is too big to fit on one screen, so obviously, I have it set as a scrollview object.

What I would like is for the textview widget to default to showing the bottom of the text whereas the user would scroll up to see the top, rather than current default of display starting from the top requiring the user to scroll down to see the bottom of the large string.

My xml file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" >
    </View>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="500"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InfoText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hugeMultiLineString"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" >
    </View>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/export"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Export" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/importFromRemote"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Import" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dirlist"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dirt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exit" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" >
    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following within your activity:

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
     }
});
```

I'm not sure about an XML attribute that will do this.

Comment: Thanks.  Your alternative works.  It appears that my main problem was that I was trying to modify the textview attribute, but there might be some xml scrollview attribute that I'll explore for future reference.  Of course, your example works excellent for the task.